# Can I access or find Unicode values of control characters?

Tags: python, unicode

Is there a way to access or find character controls in Python, like these **`NUL, DEL, CR, LF, BEL`** which is its form as a single **ASCII** Unicode character to use as a parameter in the `ord()` *built-in* method to get a numeric value.

Comment: Typically, you get them by already knowing their numerical value, e.g. getting NULL with `chr(0)` or `'\x00'`.  The ones you usually want already have special escapes, like `'\0'`, `'\n'`, etc.

Comment: The `unicodedata` module has a `lookup` function which lets you lookup characters by name: `unicodedata.lookup("NULL") == '\x00'`, but the names for most are probably harder to remember than the actual ASCII value.

Comment: using the `chr` method works directly fine and in the way I plan the question. Although I don't mention the use of the `unicode` library but I think it is very useful too.

Comment: @chepner That would be a good answer, especially since OP says that your suggestion would work for the purposes of their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find their Unicode representation on the [ASCII page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

| Key | Unicode | Unicode-Hex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NUL | ␀ | \u2400 |
| DEL | ␡ | \u2421 |
| CR | ␍ | \u240d |
| LF | ␊ | \u240a |
| BEL | ␇ | \u2407 |

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the "Unicode" column contains _a visual representation of_ the control character in Unicode, which of course is a separate code point entirely, and the "Unicode-Hex" column contains the Python escape code for this glyph. ASCII NUL (0x00) is simply U+0000 in Unicode, etc.

Answer (score -1):

To *"access"* or *"search"* to the control characters, [unicode database](https://python-docs-es.readthedocs.io/es/3.11/library/unicodedata.html?highlight=unicodedata.lookup) module provides access to a set of data of characters through different methods by each type or name representation. I was a bit confused as to its representation in the text data type format and how you could use it `ord` function;  **`lookup`** returns the name of the corresponding character thus solving the unknown about the subject to *"search"* control characters by gap unicode characters due to little experience or knowledge of the library and **ASCII** standards.

It is also important to note that the question is vaguely phrased and also does not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or algorithm problem, and since these characters have different representations and they make them not only usable in form of text or letters or even names of control characters, this due to the wide variety in which **ASCII** is ruled, this does not mean that the question could not be answered because it is known that from the beginning it started as a problem for which a clarification or explanation has been provided to the doubts presented on this post.